# HTML Canvas: Two clients writing at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having trouble implementing an *online* HTML5 Canvas with **nodejs** as a server between the clients.

One single user can paint alone with no problem, but when another clients comes in, and **paints at the same time**, the following happens:
[image: HTML5 Canvas problem with two clients]

**Client1** is the (X,Y) position of the mouse of the first client, and **Client2** is the (X,Y) position of the second client. So when the second client paints, **my program draws a line between the two points**.

Here you can browse the client JS code, where the **draw** function is responsible for painting the data received from the nodejs server:

```
App.draw = function(x, y, type, color, clear) {

    if(clear != true) {

        App.ctx.strokeStyle = color;

        if (type === "dragstart") {

            App.ctx.beginPath();

    //alert("Me muevo a X: " + x + " e Y: " + y);

            return App.ctx.moveTo(x, y);

        } else if (type === "drag") {

            App.ctx.lineTo(x, y);

            return App.ctx.stroke();

        } else {

            return App.ctx.closePath();
        }

    } else {

        // Store the current transformation matrix
        App.ctx.save();

        // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
        App.ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        App.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, App.canvas.width, App.canvas.height);

        // Restore the transform
        App.ctx.restore();

    }

};
```

Comment: You'll need to store the start/end points for each connected user, won't you?

Comment: It seems like you have only one active path and you don't check who started the path, who continues it and who finishes it. You need to maintain a separate path for each user.

Answer (score 3):

As you are sharing the same path the path will consist of a mixed set of points including both the clients.

To avoid this you can use one of two techniques:

## Solution 1

Complete a single stroke completely each time a new point is received (per client). This will reduce the current path to just that single stroke:

```
App.ctx.beginPath();
App.ctx.moveTo(oldX, oldY);  /// previous point for this client
App.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
App.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
App.ctx.stroke();
```

## Solution 2

Use two canvases layered on top of each other. Assign one layer per client. This way they are completely independent of each other and you can, if needed, merge them to one if you need to save the result as an image:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="client1" ... ></canvas>
    <canvas id="client2" ... ></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    }
.wrapper > canvas {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
```

Then use different context variables assigned to each client. One way can be:

```
App.ctx = [ctx1, ctx2];
```

Then in your function use parameter `client` as an index (ie. 0 or 1 in this case):

```
App.draw = function(client, x, y, type, color, clear) {

    if(clear != true) {

        App.ctx[client].strokeStyle = color;

        if (type === "dragstart") {

            App.ctx[client].beginPath();

    //alert("Me muevo a X: " + x + " e Y: " + y);

            return App.ctx[client].moveTo(x, y);

        } else if (type === "drag") {

            App.ctx[client].lineTo(x, y);
            App.ctx[client].stroke();     /// this has no return value

            return;

        } else {

            App.ctx[client].closePath();
            return
        }

    } else {

        // Store the current transformation matrix
        App.ctx[client].save();

        // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
        App.ctx[client].setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        App.ctx[client].clearRect(0, 0, App.canvas.width, App.canvas.height);

        // Restore the transform
        App.ctx[client].restore();
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting...2+ people drawing on 1 canvas raises the same kind of problems raised in accounting transactions.  +1 for your first solution where every drawing is “atomic” -- the current drawing must be fully started & completed before another drawing is attempted.

Comment: A tougher problem is “concurrency”.  Consider 2 people drawing an “X”—one red pen, one blue pen.  Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/SURG2/   From Reds perspective, Red draws a line and then receives Blue’s line so the blue line is over the red line.  Opposite for Blue.  The 2 drawings are not identical.  You could timestamp everyones draws  but that would mean delaying drawing for all computers until the server resolved “race situations”.  This delay results in users dragging to create a line but not having the line visibly drawn until it round-trips to the server—visually confusing!

Comment: @markE ref. sol #2: this is solved by keeping track of order determined by for example connection order. Replicate order (of canvas layers) on all clients which connects sending meta-data on the socket for this when a client connects. As the contexts/Paths are isolated the order of events doesn't matter that much, just keep a client ID on each "packet" so each client know which context to associate the data with. Timestamps wouldn't work so well as clients wouldn't necessarily be synchronized (clock is off, different time zone etc). Makes sense?

Comment: re: Timestamps: no client timestamps...server maintains timestamps based on order received from drawing computers & re-broadcasts to all in first-in-first-out order.  Sol#2 has a z-index problem. EG. bottom red canvas (z-index=0) can't draw on top of blue canvas (z-index=1) if needed. One idea is using compositing destination-over to adjust for z-indexing, but fails when trying to interlace more than 2 layers.  Seems that getting *exactly identical* drawings everywhere == routing all draws thru server (==noticeable latency to drawers, ==possible drawer confusion). Cool mental exercise! :)